# DataGrid_CellFormatting,Why VS2010 gives out an absence error in XML name space?

Tags: c#, datagrid

Whether it is possible to correct it? CellPainting plus with the same problem?
Also the ItemDataBound function, it it seems треебует system.web.UI interests
Where it to take?
(C# language)